# Using jQuery to add classes and tags to the first link in a list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to modify my ul to be Bootstrap compatible. I have most of the code working fine, but for some reason, my anchor tag isn't being affected by my jQuery code. Here's what it's supposed to look like:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And you can see here what I have done so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/NL5M8/

If you inspect the store anchor, you'll see that the classes, data-toggle and caret are not being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `.bootstrapNav > li > ul` is wrong, `li` is not a child of `bootstrapNav` it is the child of `ul` which is inside `bootstrapNav` so change the selector to `$('.bootstrapNav > ul > li > ul')` or `$('.bootstrapNav li > ul')`

```
$('.bootstrapNav li > ul').addClass('dropdown-toggle').parent('li').addClass('dropdown').find('a:first').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown').addClass('dropdown-toggle').append('<span class="caret"></span>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cBCeF/)

Comment: Missed that.... thanks! originally, bootstrapNav was on the ul element, then i moved it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
bootstrapNav>li
```

doesn't exist, you probably want `bootstrapNav>ul>li`

http://jsfiddle.net/NL5M8/1/